# Show that ${ }^{\circ}\left(C^{\circ}\right)$ smallest closed convex balanced subset of $\mathcal{X}$ containing $C$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a real locally convex Hausdorff topological vector space, let $C$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathcal{X}$, and let $D$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathcal{X}^{*}$. The absolute polar set of $C$ is
$$
C^{\circ}=\left\{x^{*} \in \mathcal{X}^{*}|(\forall x \in C) \quad|\left\langle x, x^{*}\right\rangle \mid \leqslant 1\right\}
$$
and the absolute pre-polar of $D$ is
$$
{ }^{\circ} D=\left\{x \in \mathcal{X}\left|\left(\forall x^{*} \in D\right) \quad\right|\left\langle x, x^{*}\right\rangle \mid \leqslant 1\right\}.
$$
What we want to show that is ${ }^{\circ}\left(C^{\circ}\right)$ smallest closed convex balanced subset of $\mathcal{X}$ containing $C$.

Following the standard steps, I have showed that

1. $C^{\circ}$ and ${ }^{\circ} D$ are convex and balanced;
2. $C \subset{ }^{\circ}\left(C^{\circ}\right)$;
3. $C^{\circ}=\left({ }^{\circ}\left(C^{\circ}\right)\right)^{\circ}$.

But I am stuck in how to prove ${ }^{\circ}\left(C^{\circ}\right)$ smallest closed convex balanced subset of $\mathcal{X}$ containing $C$, can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick $B$ a closed convex balanced subset of $\mathcal{X}$ containing $C$. We want to prove that ${}^{\circ}(C^{\circ}) \subset B$. If we prove that $B = {}^{\circ}(B^{\circ})$, we are done. The equality is clear if $B$ is empty. Therefore, we assume that $B$ is non-empty.
Since you have proved that $B \subset {}^{\circ}(B^{\circ})$ for any subset $B$ of $\mathcal{X}$, I will only consider the opposite inclusion.

Pick $x \in \mathcal{X}-B$. Then $x$ is not in ${}^{\circ}(B^{\circ})$ if and only if there exists $h \in \mathcal{X}^{\star}$ such that $|h| \leqslant 1$ on $B$ and $|h(x)| > 1$. We will apply the following *Geometric Hahn-Banach theroem*:

> **Theorem** (Hahn-Banach) Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a real locally convex vector space, $A, B \subset \mathcal{X}$ disjoint and non-empty convex subsets. We assume that $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed. Then there exists $h \in \mathcal{X}^{\star}$, $r, s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$ \forall a \in A, \forall b \in B,\ h(b) < r < s < h(a) $$

Set $A = \{x\}$ and $B$ as above. By assumption $B$ is a non-empty closed convex and $A$ is clearly a compact convex of $\mathcal{X}$. Let $h$, $r$ and $s$ as in the theorem. Since $b$ is balanced, we have
$$ \forall b \in B,\ h(-b) < r $$
Thus $\forall b \in B,\ |h(b)| < r$. In particular $r$ is positive and up to divide $h$ by $r$, we can assume that $r = 1$ and $s > 1$. So $h$ is the linear form we were looking for.

Comment: Got! Thank you very much!